# Windows dock software with stack docklets

Tags: windows-7, windows, dock, rocketdock

I'm looking for some windows dock software like ObjectDock or RocketDock that has stack docklets.

eg. I could add a stack docklet icon to the main dock, and when I mouseover it, a new dock appears above the icon. Or at least some dock software that can open folders inside the dock itself, not opening the folder using common explorer.

Oh, it has to be compatible with Windows7.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found the answer myself.

What I was looking for was exactly called "Stack Docklet". There is a version for both ObjectDock and RocketDock.